# Change file encoding without information losses in intellij idea

Tags: encoding, utf-8, intellij-idea, cp1251

Is it possible to change file's encoding from UTF-8 to windows1251 without cyrillic information lost. Because when I explicitely change the encoding, all cyrillic symbols become unreadable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: new IDE versions can convert encodings:

- http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

---

The problem is that IntelliJ IDEA doesn't actually convert your file encoding from `UTF-8` to `windows-1251`, what happens is that you tell IntelliJ IDEA to treat `UTF-8` file as being encoded in `windows-1251`, so you will see garbage in the editor. The actual file on disk remains in `UTF-8`.

You have to use some external tool to perform the conversion, such as **iconv**:

```
iconv.exe -f utf-8 -t windows-1251 <input file> > <output file>
```

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of IntelliJ will ask if you would like to "Reload" or "Convert" the file to the new encoding.

I had a file that was displayed using `UTF-8` but was actually written in `x-macRoman`.  I selected `x-macRoman` and chose "Reload" so that the encoding would be used to interpret the file, I then chose `UTF-8` and selected "Convert". Now my file is properly encoded as `UTF-8`

***Tested With:** version 12.1.3*